# Unable to align word to the left

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, text-align

I'm trying to create a table with 2 table data and 2 table headers. After researching about html codes, I realized the way to shift the word to the left is `Text-Align="Left"` as written below. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I'm not using any CSS but just plain html codes.

Here is my  codes :

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 189px; height: 23px;">Full Name:</th>
        <td style="width: 1910px; height: 23px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text="" Text-Align="Left"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <th style="width: 21px; height: 23px;">Contact:</th>
        <td style="width: 684px; height: 23px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblContact" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<asp:Label />` will generate an `<span>` HTML tag, which is `inline`, and `text-align` to it is undefined, otherwise, set `text-align` of the `td`:

```
<td style="width: 1910px; height: 23px; text-align: center;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
```

Or make your `<asp:Label />` as a `block` element:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text=""
    style="display: block; text-align: center;"
></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 189px; height: 23px;">Full Name:</td>
        <td style="width: 1910px; height: 23px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text="" Text-Align="Left"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 21px; height: 23px;">Contact:</td>
        <td style="width: 684px; height: 23px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblContact" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```